# Proving the sum of two independent Cauchy Random Variables is Cauchy

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, convolution

Is there any method to show that the sum of two independent Cauchy random variables is Cauchy? I know that it can be derived using Characteristic Functions, but the point is, I have not yet learnt Characteristic Functions. I do not know anything about Complex Analysis, Residue Theorem, etc.

I would want to prove the statement only using Real Calculus. Feel free to use Double Integrals if you please.

On searching, I found [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/statistics-show-that-the-sum-of-two-independent-cauchy-random-variables-is-cauchy.577953/). However, I was wondering if I could get some help directly on the convolution formula:

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\pi^2}.\frac{1}{1+x^2}.\frac{1}{1+(z-x)^2}dx\tag{1}$$

Here I have supposed that $X,Y$ are Independent Standard Cauchy. But I think the general formula can be derived easily after some substitutions. I need some help on how to proceed from $(1)$.

EDIT: Just as what the hint in the hyperlink said, I got the answer using that hint. However, I am not quite sure that the hint is algebraically correct. Maybe there has been some typing mistake in the book.

Comment: Can you write the integrand in the form $\displaystyle \frac{a(x)}{1+x^2} + \frac{b(x)}{1+(z-x)^2}$ and break up that integral into the sum of two integrals that might be computable more easily?

Comment: Could you provide some more insight into finding $a$ and $b$? I am not really able to think of such functions whose integral I can compute easily.

Comment: Read about the _partial fractions_ method in a calculus text or on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Comment: I know what partial fractions are, of course. I am saying that I do not understand how we can select $a(x)$ and $b(x)$.

Comment: The main problem is that by using a partial fraction decomposition we introduce an eliminable discontinuity, then integration is not straighforward if we want to stay on the real line. However, there is a way to circumvent this issue, just see below.

Comment: Actually, if you observe my Partial Fraction Decomposition, it follows that upon integration, the first and third terms together yield $log1% as $x$ approaches $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Hence that will not be problem.

Comment: Apparently someone misunderstood the convolution formula and edited the original work; unfortunately that edit was accepted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We may exploit the Lagrange identity:
$$ (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2 \tag{1}$$
to state:
$$ I_z=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+(z-x)^2)}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x(z-x))^2+(z-2x)^2}\tag{2}$$
and by replacing $x$ with $x+\frac{z}{2}$ in the last integral, we get:
$$ I_z = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+\frac{z^2}{4}-x^2)^2+4x^2}\tag{3}$$
hence $I_z$ just depends on $\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4}\right)$. For the sake of brevity, let:
$$ J(m)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2-m)^2+4x^2}\tag{4} $$
for any $m\geq 1$. With the change of variable $x-\frac{m}{x}=u$ we have:
$$ J(m) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\frac{u}{\sqrt{4m+u^2}}}{8m+2m \,u^2}\,du = \frac{1}{2m}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{4+u^2}=\frac{\pi}{4m}\tag{5}$$
from which it follows that:

> $$ I_z = \frac{\pi}{2+\frac{z^2}{2}}=\frac{2\pi}{4+z^2}.\tag{6}$$

The interesting thing is that this proof is just a variation of the proof of the relation between the arithmetic-geometric mean ([AGM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean)) and the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) ($K(k)$).

Comment: How do you get equation (5)? $u/\sqrt{4m + u^2} = 0$?

Comment: @Alain: that function is odd and integrable when multiplied by $\frac{1}{1+u^2}$, so it does not really contribute to the integral.

Comment: And that term comes from $(1 + \frac{m}{x^2}) dx = du$?

Comment: @Alain: exactly.

Comment: how did you get 5 from 4?

Answer (score 8):

So after no satisfactory answer to this question, here I am posting the ultimate hint which I found after a long hard search and from which the problem becomes immediately obvious.

> Decompose $\dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+(z-x)^2)}=\dfrac{1}{z^2(z^2+4)}\big[\dfrac{2zx}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{2z^2-2zx}{1+(z-x)^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{1+(z-x)^2}\big]$

I post this keeping in mind that there must be an online record which I may also use for my personal computations at a later stage.